# Troubles trying to convert rows that contain a certain text using dictionary and map

Tags: python, string, pandas, data-science

I am trying to rename rows in my dataframe using a dictionary and the map function. Problem is some of the rows don't have the same text.

Here is the code I have:

```
fb_posts['title'] = fb_posts['title'].astype(str)
def converts(i):
  if 'link' in i:
    i == 'link'
  elif 'post' in i:
    i == 'post'
  elif 'status' in i:
    i == 'stats'
  elif 'timeline' in i:
    i == 'timeline'
  return i
fb_posts['title'] = fb_posts['title'].apply(converts(i))
```

So i started off by converting everything in the column into strings so I could find if a string contained a certain letter and convert the string according if it did.

However this returns the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-310-6ddc37cbbb4d> in <module>()
----> 1 fb_posts['title'] = fb_posts['title'].apply(converts(i))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2532         # if we are a string, try to dispatch
   2533         if isinstance(func, compat.string_types):
-> 2534             return self._try_aggregate_string_function(func, *args, **kwds)
   2535 
   2536         # handle ufuncs and lambdas

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _try_aggregate_string_function(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    307             return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    308 
--> 309         raise ValueError("{arg} is an unknown string function".format(arg=arg))
    310 
    311     def _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):

ValueError: Person updated his status. is an unknown string function
```

Here is a sample of my database:

```
 title   
Person shared a link.
Person shared a post.
Person posted on x's timeline
Person posted on y's timeline
Person posted on a's timeline
```

Comment: `converts` uses `==` comparison operator where you probably meant to use `=` for assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small number of categories, a simple loop may be efficient:

```
for x in ['link', 'post', 'status', 'timeline']:
    fb_posts.loc[fb_posts['title'].str.contains(x, regex=False), 'title'] = x
```

Regex solutions may also work, but typically are more efficient where you have a large number of categories.

Answer (score 2):

Again using `findall` with `|`

```
df.title.str.findall('link|post|status|timeline').str[-1]
Out[103]: 
0        link
1        post
2    timeline
3    timeline
4    timeline
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try either -

```
fb_posts['title'] = fb_posts['title'].apply(converts)
```

OR

```
fb_posts['title'] = fb_posts['title'].apply(lambda x: converts(x))
```

You need to pass a `function` object as a parameter to the `apply` function

Comment: This would probably work but the `converts` function has a syntax problem that needs to be fixed first.

Comment: Yes, missed that. `=` and not `==`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer...

I kept close to your code, but changed the function a bit.

```
def converts(row):
    for i in ['link', 'post', 'status', 'timeline']:
        if i in row['title']:
            return i
    return row['title']

fb_posts['title'] = fb_posts['title'].apply(lambda x: converts(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I get the error  message 'TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' with this

Comment: That's weird; axis is an argument for `apply`. You sure you copied it exactly?